# shuffle()関数の配列の使い方について

Tags: php

shuffle()関数の使い方について

ある解説を見ているとshuffle()関数について

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

shuffle([1, 3, 5, 8])とすると配列の中身がシャッフルされ
[8, 5, 1, 3]、あるいは[5, 1, 8, 3]のように返ってくるとの説明があります。

xamppでブラウザ表示させるために　echo や　print_r()などを使ってみたのですが、

"Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference inC:\xampp\htdocs…"

としか返ってきません。「変数に代入させてくれ」というような意味だと解釈し
以下のようなに記述すると

```
$ar = array(1, 3, 5, 8);
shuffle($ar);
print_r($ar);
```

---

このようにかえってきます。

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 )
```

shuffle()関数について入門書の類では索引を見てもほぼ出てきません。
ウェブを眺めてみると公式サイトにあるような使用例か複雑なものばかり出てきます。

shuffle — 配列をシャッフルする(PHP公式)
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.shuffle.php
使用例

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 20);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
?>
```

これだと確かに　1から20の値がランダムに生成されます。

```
5 13 17 18 11 15 20 14 4 12 6 8 2 1 10 19 7 9 3 16
```

が、上の添付画像にある

shuffle([1, 3, 5, 8]) が[8, 5, 1, 3]という風にシャッフルされるという説明とは少し違うと思います。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どのようにすれば、このように配列がシャッフルされて出てくるようになるのでしょうか？

ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 単に表示形式の問題かと思いますが、画像の様に表示したい場合は、`echo json_encode($ar) . PHP_EOL;`  などとします。

Comment: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 ) `と表示されるとおっしゃっていますが、私の環境だと、1358の数字が正しくバラバラに表示されます。`Array( [0] => 1 [1] => 8  [2] => 3   [3] => 5)`のように。そもそも何かソースが間違っていたりしませんか？

Comment: 配列が値がシャッフルされランダムに並び替えられますので、私の出したサンプルと同じ値の配列が出てくることは稀だと思います。